# Return statement in a if/else statement doesn't return value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this function I would like to return a list if it's not empty. To check is the list is empty I use the `if not data:` and to test if it is filled with something I use `elif data:` but the `return` statement is not executed when `len(data)` equal to 13. What could be the reason?

When the list is empty the function is called again with new `start` and `end` parameters until `data` is filled with something.

```
Class MyClass:

    def downloadHistoryOHLC(url, start, end):

        http = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(http.read().decode())

        print('length is', len(data))      # Here I test if list is filled  

        if not data:

            ''' Add 366 days to start date if list is empty '''

            start = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') + timedelta(days=366)
            start = str(start.isoformat()+'Z')

            end = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') + timedelta(days=366)
            end = str(end.isoformat()+'Z')

            MyClass.downloadHistoryOHLC(url, start, end) # if list is empty I execute the same function with new parameters

        elif data:

            return data
```

When I execute the function I can see the length of the list is 13 but no data is returned.

```
In [844]: mylist = MyClass.downloadHistoryOHLC(start, end, coin_id, name)
length is 0
length is 0
length is 0
length is 0
length is 13

In [845]: mylist

In [846]:
```

Comment: you've missed a return of the returned value in MyClass.downloadHistoryOHLC(). it should be like "return MyClass.downloadHistoryOHLC(..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return value of recursive function python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845974/return-value-of-recursive-function-python)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would work better with an else instead of an elif:

```
else:
    return data
```

Comment: Same problem with `else`. Event `print('length of list is', len(data))` followed by `if len(data)==13: return data` doesn't work ((

Comment: As noted by @Paul in the comment section I missed the `return MyClass.downloadHistoryOHLC(...`

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Paul in the comment section I missed the return when calling the function.

```
Class MyClass:

    def downloadHistoryOHLC(url, start, end):

        http = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(http.read().decode())

        print('length is', len(data))      # Here I test if list is filled  

        if not data:

            ''' Add 366 days to start date if list is empty '''

            start = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') + timedelta(days=366)
            start = str(start.isoformat()+'Z')

            end = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') + timedelta(days=366)
            end = str(end.isoformat()+'Z')

            return(MyClass.downloadHistoryOHLC(url, start, end)) # if list is empty I execute the same function with new parameters

        return data
```